# COMExeception was unhandled

Tags: c#

No momento de inicializar a classe `SpeechRecognition`, ele aparece esse erro e não da seguimento a minha aplicação:

> {"Falha na recuperação de fábrica de classes COM do componente com
>   CLSID {49428A60-C997-4D0E-9808-9E326C178D58} devido ao seguinte erro:
>   80040154 Classe não registrada (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x80040154
>   (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))."}

Acho que no meu caso possa ser incompatibilidade do VS (Visual Studio 2012) 32 bits, com meu Windows 10 64 bits.